# Trying to figure out name of data struct

Tags: c

While going through some code, I came accross this block of code:

```
struct option options[] = {
    {"help", 0, 0, HELP_OPTION},
    {"minor", 1, 0, MINOR_OPTION},
    {"dac", 1, 0, DAC_OPTION},
    {0, 0, 0, 0}
};
```

I know what a struct is, but I have never seen a "{0, 0, 0, 0}" data struct. Does anyone know what the name for the "{0,0,0,0}" data struct is?

Comment: This is an array of `struct option`. Element `3` fields are set to `0`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the name of the data struct. It's just like the others in the array except the values are 0.

Answer (score 2):

The code simply defines an array that contains several instances of `option` structures. In this case, the `{ 0, 0, 0, 0 }` is probably used to signify that it is the last item in the array (since C arrays don't have a length property).

As far as the name, it is unnamed. You can reference this structure from code using `options[3]`.